# How can i open image file after compression in Pillow Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When trying to open and compress images in Pillow-PYTHON

```
image = Image.open("some_image.jpg");

fpath = io.BytesIO();
image.save(fpath,'JPEG',dpi=[300,300], quality=image_quality);

compressed_image = Image.open(fpath.getvalue());
```

I'm getting the following error when opening the compressed image

```
TypeError: embedded NUL character
```

Any idea how i can get the image to open?

Comment: `Image.open` expects a filename. `BytesIO.getvalue()` returns the *contents*.

Comment: @RolandSmith Here is a more specific segment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330570/how-to-open-a-simple-image-using-streams-in-pillow-python

Comment: @RolandSmith Could you suggest on how i can open an image file using streams in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `BytesIO` object itself:

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image

In [2]: from io import BytesIO

In [3]: image = Image.open("foo.jpg")

In [4]: fpath = BytesIO()

In [5]: image.save(fpath,'JPEG', dpi=[300, 300], quality=40)

In [6]: fpath.seek(0)
Out[6]: 0

In [7]: compressed_image = Image.open(fpath)
```

If you don't use `fpath.seek(0)`, you'll get an error because the file position is at the end of the "file", and there is nothing to read there.